# SSO with active directory on Windows server 2012 os using edx.

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, openedx

I want to do a SSO with Windows on-prim server using edx.
How to implement this?

Comment: Did you see this? Supported Identity Providers...
https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_providers.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. Its not an azure active directory. Its an on-prime server.